# Preventing timeouts by sending $_POST values

Tags: php

I have a php file with a html form.

By clicking on the submit button of the form the same php file gets two values over `$_POST` and creates some files which will take some minutes.

I am afraid of getting timeouts because the browser keeps on loading, till the files are created.

Does it will fix the timeout issue by `set_time_limit(0)` or should I mention something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's enough with `set_time_limit( 0 );`

Is it a upload? If it's not you can use:

```
ignore_user_abort( true );
```

Could be useful to use increase the memory limit too

```
ini_set( 'memory_limit', '128M' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `set_time_limit(timeout)` function is a convenience wrapper around `ini_set('max_execution_time', timeout)`. You can modify your php.ini to set this property to 0, or just use `set_time_limit` function to increase (or remove) timeout for this script only.

And yes normally it does the trick without anything else. Server-side only : i guess browsers have an internal timeout too and that they cut connection when they don't get any response for a time.

BTW you can think about using ajax to call your script and create the file : it's better for the user not to see a blank page during file creation, and you will avoid this browser timeout problem.